# Spring WebSocket doesn't replay to subscribers

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring) to understand how webSocket works in Spring.

My controller class:

```
  @Controller
  public class TestController {
  
  @MessageMapping("/chat")
  @SendTo("/topic/messages")
  public String greeting(String message) {
    System.out.println("HelloWorld"); // <--- The code is executed
    return "HelloWorld";
  }
}
```

My WebSocket class:

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
  public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
  }
}
```

My js client:

```
export function connect() {
  var socket = new SockJS("http://192.168.1.63:5001/chat");
  stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  //stompClient.debug = null;
  stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
    console.log(frame);
    stompClient.subscribe("/topic/messages", messageOutput => {
      console.log(messageOutput);  // <-- Nothing here!
    });
  });
}

export function disconnect() {
  if (stompClient != null) {
    stompClient.disconnect();
  }
  console.log("Disconnected");
}

export function sendMessage() {
  stompClient.send(
    "/app/chat",
    {},
    "this is only a test!"
  );
}
```

what happens in Chrome Inspector: [Chrome Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbZ7S.png)

So, it seems as the server side doesn't replay at client though the "greeting" method is invoked.